# logic 4 table with edit options

Tags: php, html

I want to display a list as described in the link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgPwE.jpg
As soon as the value in dropdown is choosen. Then it should save the value immediately.

**EDIT:-**

the code that i have written which is working...This is in loop.

```
    <tr>
    <td><?php $number += 1; echo $number;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['db1_CON_NUMBER'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $record['DB1_status'];?></td>
    <td width="100" class="rtodata">
       <select name="action_db2" id=<?php echo $record['db1_CON_NUMBER']; ?>  onchange="mark_doubleones_1('doubleones1.php?tab=doubleones&id='+this.id+'&value='+this.value);">
            <option value=""<?php if( $action_db1 == '') echo 'SELECTED';?></option>
            <option value="yes"<?php if( $action_db2 == 'yes') echo 'SELECTED';?>>Ok to Invoice</option>
            <option value="no"<?php if( $action_db2 == 'no') echo 'SELECTED';?>>Exclude</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

and in javascript

```
function mark_doubleones_1(url){
    document.location.href = url;
}
```

Now the other method which @mistabell suggested,

```
<select name="action_db2" id=<?php echo $record['db1_CON_NUMBER']; ?>  onchange="updateItem(this)">
```

and the story is below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be better to seperate your javascript from the element on the page and avoid an onClick HTML reference.  Use this...

```
jQuery('.rtodata select').bind('change', function (e) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax-file.php',
        data: {
            value: jQuery('select option:selected', jQuery(e.currentTarget).parent()).val()
        },
        success: function (r) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (error, t, msg) {
            alert('failed');
        }
    });
}
```

With this method, `ajax-file.php` will receive your value via `$_POST`.  This method does not require any modification to your HTML and is more efficient because you don't need to use `onClick="...."` thus reducing the amount of HTML that must be downloaded to view the page.