# jQuery $.post() and IE7

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

On IE7, I'm not getting a response back from my POST:

```
function updateItem(item) {
  $.post("updater.php",{key:item.id, value:item.value},function(response) {
    $('#response').html(response);
  });
}

<div id="response"></div>
<select id="PRIMARY_KEY" onchange="updateItem(this)">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>

<?php
  echo 'UPDATED KEY: ' . $_POST['key'] . ' TO: ' . $_POST['value'];
?>
```

It works with all of my other browsers.  Why is that?

Edit: Initially, I was trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135324/logic-4-table-with-edit-options/4142549#4142549).

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting any response back? What if you put an alert("test") into the response function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : (2 modifications : `value`'s... value and `<option value="1">1</option>`)

```
<script>
    function updateItem(item) {
  $.post("updater.php",{key:item.id, value:item.options[item.selectedIndex].value}, function(response) {
    $('#response').html(response);   });

}
</script>
<div id="response"></div>
<select id="primary_key" onchange="updateItem(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

I used jsfiddle, IE7 and debugBar to find those. http://jsfiddle.net/d3xk8/

Answer (score 1):

There is error in setting `innerHTML` through jquery.

Use `document.getElementById("#response").innerHTML = response;`

Answer (score 0):

Usually if I don't get a response back from a function it means that I've misformatted the data I'm trying to pass. I'd recommend putting double quotes around the string that you are echoing and seeing if that works.

Comment: I don't think adding double quotes would change the statement.  I'm just sending a concatenated string that I'm receiving on other browsers.

Comment: I know but jQuery sometimes insists on double quotes, especially in responses from PHP. I.E. might be trickier than the others.